# Check if a user leaves a view function

Tags: python, django, django-views

Lets say I have a `realArray` and a `tempArray`. I want to add all the data in the `tempArray` into the `realArray` if a user clicks something that would cause them to leave the view they are currently on. This could be closing the browser, searching something in their browser, clicking a bookmark, or clicking a different link within the website. Any thoughts would be appreciated:)

Comment: I think you can only do this via javascript  and post to the backend when the event happens

Comment: @Anthony Perot Is this something I shouldn't be typically doing? Because I can't reason a different way to do it.

Comment: are `realArray` and `tempArray` in the django view? After render to the browser you leave the view so you can't update realArray in the view. As Anthony said you'd need to use some javascript to update a draft value for realArray. Alternatively update the corresponding fields immediately after changes with javascript.